# Broadleaf with SAP Commerce

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, broadleaf-commerce

We consider using broadleaf for one of our client who need to revamp his B2B site.  Everything with broadleaf looks very good, but one major challenge is this client have all his product, ordering, promo, etc. in SAP Commerce.

Does anyone have ever integrated or override broadleaf to call/persist entities in SAP Commerce instead of the normal relational database?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think ESB(Mule,OpenESB... etc) is the best solution for this kind of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Broadleaf is used to integrate with systems like SAP often.    There are a number of approaches to integrating with SAP.   The most common approach would involve mapping the SAP data and integrating it into the Broadleaf tables.    As part of the mapping process, you will come across some incompatible structure changes and you can modify the Broadleaf structures to match the data from your source system.

Similarly, once a cart is submitted in Broadleaf, the common pattern is to queue the order and then run an integration process to push the order to the backend systems.

For promotions, we see two common approaches.   If the promotions must originate in SAP, then, similar to product data, the promotion would be integrated into the Broadleaf offer tables so that cart pricing works as expected.

It is also common to use the Broadleaf promotion engine and then map the adjustments back into generic discount structures in SAP.